# Omit fields in the rails scaffold templates?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am customizing my scaffold templates and looking to omit certain fields like this:

`attributes.reject(&:password_digest?).each do |attribute|`

which is used to not display the password field etc.  I am looking to always hide for example the tenant `account_id` column and a few others that never need to be the views etc.

I have looked up the reject method but it is not obvious to me how I specify multiple columns etc.  Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Use [except](https://apidock.com/rails/Hash/except) to filter keys from a hash:

```rb
{a: 1, b: 2, c: 3}.except(:a, :c)
# => {:b=>2}
```

Edit: Given it´s not a hash you could do `reject` in combination with 'any?':

```rb
attributes.reject{ |attr| [:password_digest?, :other_method?].any?{ |method| attr.send(method) } }
```

Comment: It's not a hash in the Rails generator so this does not work.